# Why does adding an image texture node to the normals section make the face look half light/half dark?

Tags: texturing, materials, normals

I'm adding image textures to the various nodes on my character, and this happens to some of my meshes when I add a normals texture:

[image]

The face of the character is half light, half dark.  This happens intermittently, and doesn't seem to affect all of the mesh: if you look at the image, the hair doesn't seem to be affected.

My process for adding the normals texture:

- Change *bump* to *normals* map (I have to do this because the importer defaults to *bump*)
- Change the color to *Image Texture* <-- this is the point where the division happens
- Add the *normals* texture

How can I make this stop happening?

Comment: Your Image Texture node needs to be set to Non-Color instead of sRGB, also plug it into the Color input of the Normal Map, if it still doesn't work please pack your images and share your file

Comment: Is this object mirrored? Can you show us your node-tree / UV map? It looks as if your normals are flipped on one side.

Comment: @moonbots, I think that was the problem.  I had it set to sRGB.  I changed it to Non-Color and the problem went away.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *Image Texture* node needs to be set to *Non-Color* instead of *sRGB*, also plug it into the *Color* input of the *Normal Map*.